# Call a rest webservice using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, web-services, rest

So I created a server application using Java and wildfly that have multiple rest webservices. This webservice return xml and are working. This was the easy part, but now I have to make an application that is going to use the web services. This application is not a website and I have problems calling the web services. I tried

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "url, false);
    xhttp.send();
```

This url is a valid url. When I try to run the code that call this javascrip I got the following error.

```
XMLHttpRequest' is undefined
```

At first i thought tha was some missing library (i am realy new to javascript), but when I google it, I understood that this method is only usable when it runs in a web page.

I don't want the code to do this I only want to know if there is a method I can use to call a rest web service and get the xml result. If possible a method native to javascrip (not using query or others) and that can be used in a aplication and not a web site.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is a very low level approach that won't work on every browser (IE vs the rest of the world).
You should use a library that will simplify the usage of Ajax for you, and that will make your code compatible on any browser.

Comment: Remove the `"` before `"url`. Open your console, it says "Syntax error". Otherwise, this code seems valid to me

Comment: This is not really a concern anymore. `XMLHttpRequest` exists as of IE8. IE10 became EOL more than a year ago.

Comment: You write you don't want the code to work only in a webbrowse: should we assume you're working with node.js?

Comment: I thought this was kind of messy even in the last versions of IE, but that's a long time that I wouldn't try to make an HTTP request outside of a framework.

Comment: What is your calling application? If it's not web, where does the js come in? You can make a http request to your service without js from a server.